# wxWidgets wxFileSystemHandler::OpenFile() never gets called

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I extended the class `wxFileSystemHandler` to handle special protocols I use in my application. My implementation of `wxFileSystemHandler::CanOpen()` is called, recognizes the protocol and returns **TRUE**. But my implementation of `wxFileSystemHandler::OpenFile()` never gets called. I inspected the wxWidgets code and saw that the `CanOpen()` member function is called by the pointer that I registered. But when a call to `OpenFile()` is made they pass the pointer to a `wxFileSystem::MakeLocal()` member function that tries to get another pointer inside a hash map that, obviously, is not my instance.

Someone got a problem like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you doing, i.e. when do you expect your handler to be called, but in any case `MakeLocal()` is supposed to create a new instance of the same class if you mark the object as being dynamically creatable using wxRTTI macros and use the object as given otherwise. So if you really need the same *object* to be reused, you probably need to use `wxDECLARE_ABSTRACT_CLASS()` in its class. But OTOH why is it a problem to make a new instance?

Comment: Hi VZ. Thanks for your answer. I created the class to support some custom protocols. So, when I call, in my App `wxXmlResource::Get()->Load("rsrc:my_icon")`, my class should be called to handle the protocol. Indeed, the `CanOpen()` member function is called. But the `OpenFile()` don't. I actually created the class with `wxDECLARE_ABSTRACT_CLASS()` and `wxIMPLEMENT_ABSTRACT_CLASS()` but didn't work. I also tried `wxDECLARE_DYNAMIC_CLASS()` and its companion `wxIMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC_CLASS()`. Also didn't work. It should. I think I must investigate more.